# Checking exceptions with TestCaseData parameters

Tags: nunit-3.0, fluent-assertions, parameterized-tests

I'm using NUnit 3 `TestCaseData` objects to feed test data to tests and Fluent Assertions library to check exceptions thrown.

Typically my `TestCaseData` object contains two parameters `param1` and `param2` used to create an instance of some object within the test and upon which I then invoke methods that should/should not throw exceptions, like this:

```
var subject = new Subject(param1, param2);
subject.Invoking(s => s.Add()).Should().NotThrow();
```

or

```
var subject = new Subject(param1, param2);
subject.Invoking(s => s.Add()).Should().Throw<ApplicationException>();
```

Is there a way to pass `NotThrow()` and `Throw<ApplicationException>()` parts as specific conditions in a third parameter in `TestCaseData` object to be used in the test? Basically I want to parameterize the test's expected result (it may be an exception of some type or no exception at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this:

```
using ExceptionResult = Action<System.Func<UserDetail>>;

        [Test]
        [TestCaseSource(typeof(UserEndpointTests), nameof(AddUserTestCases))]
        public void User_Add(string creatorUsername, Role role, ExceptionResult result)
        {
            var endpoint = new UserEndpoint(creatorUsername);
            var person = GeneratePerson();
            var request = GenerateCreateUserRequest(person, role);

            // Assertion comes here
            result(endpoint.Invoking(e => e.Add(request)));
        }

        private static IEnumerable AddUserTestCases
        {
            get
            {
                yield return new TestCaseData(TestUserEmail, Role.User, new ExceptionResult(x => x.Should().Throw<ApplicationException>())
                    .SetName("{m} (Regular User => Regular User)")
                    .SetDescription("User with Regular User role cannot add any users.");

                yield return new TestCaseData(TestAdminEmail, Role.Admin, new ExceptionResult(x => x.Should().NotThrow())
                    )
                    .SetName("{m} (Admin => Admin)")
                    .SetDescription("User with Admin role adds another user with Admin role.");
            }
        }
```

No big issues with readability, besides, `SetName()` and `SetDescription()` methods in the test case source help with that.

Answer (score 1):

`[TestCaseData]` is meant for *Test Case Data*, not for assertions methods.

I would keep the `NotThrow` and `Throw` in separate tests to maintain readability.
If they share a lot of setup-logic, I would extract *that* into shared methods to reduce the size of the test method bodies.

`TestCaseData` accepts compile time values, whereas `TestCaseSource` generates them on runtime, which would be necessary to use `Throw` and `NotThrow`.

Here's a way to do it by misusing `TestCaseSource`.
The result is an unreadable test method, so please don't use this anywhere.

Anyway here goes:

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class ActionTests
{
    private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> ActionTestCaseData
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData((Action)(() => throw new Exception()), (Action<Action>)(act => act.Should().Throw<Exception>()));
            yield return new TestCaseData((Action)(() => {}), (Action<Action>)(act => act.Should().NotThrow()));
        }
    }

    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(ActionTests), nameof(ActionTestCaseData))]
    public void Calculate_Success(Action act, Action<Action> assert)
    {
        assert(act);
    }
}
```